# Periodic tick / click /crack sound from Logitech QuickCam Pro 5000 USB webcam

Tags: sound, webcam

While watching the input volume meter from my webcam in `pavucontrol`, it maxes out with a short (100ms or so) cracking sound every ~3 seconds, independently of the ambient sound. **How can I get rid of it?**

Looks like [this has already been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/151890), but the project was abandoned. I don't suppose it would help to bribe with a bounty? :)

```
$ lsusb | grep -i cam
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:08ce Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro 5000
```

From the [Linux UVC driver](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/) footnotes:

> <sup>1</sup> First and second generation Logitech webcams suffer from firmware bug
>   which make the camera somehow unstable. As the issue is
>   timing-related, the exact impact of the bug on a particular user can't
>   be predicted. If you plan to buy a Logitech webcam, consider getting
>   one of the models not affected by the bug. More information about the
>   issue, including possible workarounds, are available on the [QuickCam
>   Team](http://www.quickcamteam.net/documentation/faq/logitech-webcam-linux-usb-incompatibilities) website.
>
> <sup>2</sup> Starting at version 2.6.22, the Linux kernel includes a USB audio bug
>   fix which triggers a (possibly identical to the above) bug in first
>   and second generation Logitech webcams. See the [Linux UVC wiki](http://openfacts.berlios.de/index-en.phtml?title=Linux_UVC) for a
>   workaround.

Both references are down, so I guess that's it for this camera.

Comment: Looking at the bug report, unless this is resolved with a newer kernel, looks like a dead end. Can you try a newer kernel and report back ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a firmware bug (see the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/151890)). Buying a new webcam seems the only solution.